# How to configure jooq to generate particular table with all types

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

How do we need to add configuration so that jooq generates only a specific table that is configured and it should include all types also.

In the existing project they have disabled table generation  `<includeTables>false</includeTables>` , but now i need a particular table to be generated. If I enable it to be true, then it generates all the tables. So i have tried using  `<includes>Table_Name</includes>` after this it generates only that particular table and all other stuff like udts types are not generated.

Comment: Why is the table generation disabled?

Comment: Until now we were not working with generated table pojos directly, we always performed CRUD operations using stored procedures, but now i have a requirement to work with Table accessing / writing to it using jooq dls context and hence i need that particular table pojo to be generated

Comment: IMHO there is no way to generate one table and all necessary UDT etc. Why don't you generate it for all tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a pending feature request to enhance the `<includes>` and `<excludes>` regular expressions to allow for applying them per object type: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5263. Currently, this is not possible.

But your `<includes>` regular expression could include the table and all the UDTs that you need, e.g.

```xml
<includes>
  table_name
| udt_name_1
| udt_name_2
</includes>
```

Alternatively, provide full qualification as needed:

```xml
<includes>
  schema1\.table_name
| schema2\.udt_name_1
| schema3\.udt_name_2
</includes>
```

Note that regular expressions are case sensitive by default. Use `(?i:...)` to make them case insensitive.